# I want to change bottom link when hove mouse on a post in WordPress

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, hyperlink

I want to change the link shown below in browser when mouse is hover on a link in a website.

[image]

Comment: it is the actual link of `<a>`  of which browser redirect after click like this, [Hover this and look](https://google.com)

Comment: That “below in browser” portion is actually called the _status bar_, and together with that keyword, you should be able to research the rest yourself.

Comment: What do you want to change it to? The point of this text is to show the user whether the link wants to take them.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the href attribute in the anchor element when the user hovers (mousenter) over it - that will be shown in the browser's status bar.

And then when the user comes to actually click - which will have a mousedown event - you change the href attribute back to what it was.

This feels a bit 'sneaky', as if you are trying to pretend to the user that they are going to a certain url when in fact they will end up on another one, but it works and is I suppose no worse than a redirect they weren't expecting.

```html
<a href="url1" onmouseover="this.setAttribute('href','url2');" onmousedown="this.setAttribute('href','url1');">Link</a>
```